# What might cause a GL_INVALID_OPERTATION error on a call to EAGLContext presentRenderBuffer?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Any ideas what might cause `EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer` to result in a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, even though the call returns YES and the buffer seems to have the correct content?

Some details:

I am using a 3rd party library to render a texture to an off-screen framebuffer.  Because the third-party renders are slow, this is done asynchronously on a background thread using a separate `EAGLContext`, but using a sharegroup in common with the main thread's rendering context so that the final texture may be picked up from there for use in on-screen rendering.

There is a single framebuffer that is set up once and re-used:

```
GLuint _frameBuffer = 0;
GLuint _stencilRenderBuffer = 0;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_stencilRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, stencilRenderBuffer);
```

And then, for each new texture rendered by the 3rd party library, a new texture is created to receive the final rendered texture:

```
GLuint _texture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _frameBufferTexture, 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) ;
if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // handle it
}

glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

// {CALL TO 3rd PARTY LIBRARY IS MADE HERE}

glFinish(); // ensure third-party library is finished

BOOL result = [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];  // XCode breaks on this line
```

This has been working seemingly fine; I only discovered the error after enabling an "OpenGL ES Error" breakpoint in XCode earlier today to hunt down a different error; XCode will break on the the last line shown with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, and a subsequent call to `glGetError` returns 1282.  There are no GL errors showing before the call to presentRenderbuffer (I've put in `glGetError` calls, but have omitted them here for brevity.)

The curious thing is that the `presentRenderbuffer` call returns YES (success) even though the breakpoint shows an invalid operation error on the call.  Every new texture is presented, and used downstream to render to screen.

Still, I would like to know what is causing this, and fix it, so that it is not causing other error down the line.

Comment: Could you try adding calls to glGetError() after every OpenGLES call, just in case the error is in fact generated by an earlier call, but the XCOde error breakpoint happens to fire on the wrong line.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry if it wasn't clear above, but I did put glGetError calls (in while loops to ensure clear all of the errors) before and after the presentRenderBuffer call.  (I didn't put them after every GL call in the program - it's a huge program - but the Xcode OpenGL ES Error breakpoint

Comment: @Columbo I think the comment above was meant for you.